# How do I install IUP with MinGw

Tags: c, windows, gcc, iup

I'm learning how to make GUI applications using C and I came across the IUP Toolkit. Reading through the tutorials I am stuck on how to actually configure the toolkit with MinGw so that I can compile a basic window program.

http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/

I'm have downloaded and copied the library into my MinGW folder and have made the basic hello world program :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iup.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  IupOpen(&argc, &argv);

  IupMessage("Hello World 1", "Hello world from IUP.");

  IupClose();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My biggest issue comes with compiling the program using gcc to compile the program as I'm not sure what exact values I need to use with the compiler flags (specifically with final -L directory)

```
gcc -o example2_1 example2_1.o -liupimglib -liup -L../../../lib/$TEC_UNAME
```

I apologise if this is a little vague but I can't say I've really done anything like this before

Comment: $TEC_UNAME is just an environment variable the whole -L parameter is simply the folder where the library is

Comment: So would I set that to my MinGw folder?

Comment: No, to "mingw4".